# IIS URL Redirect - Query String For Custom Error Page

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, iis

When users request a url that is not found, they are redirected to my custom error page. This custom error page takes the incorrect url passed as a parameter and compares it with a list of redirect urls I have on my server.

If a url is found in this list, they are then redirected to the appropriate url.

What is happening is IIS suddenly changes the way it produces the query string. When I look in the event viewer I notice that sometimes it shows up as:

UrlRedirect: /404_301.aspx?404;http://mysite.ca:80/blaaaah/ : BEGIN Processing URL

Other times:
UrlRedirect: /404_301.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/blaaaah/404.aspx : BEGIN Processing URL

This is causing conflicts with how the URL is handled for my custom error page.

<strike>Does anyone know how IIS chooses to set the query string and how I can gain more control over this?</strike>

**UPDATE:** After determining that IIS and ASP.NET are both trying to handle the 404 and redirecting them in different ways, Is there a way to only allow ASP.Net to handle the 404 redirect?

.NET Redirect:
Other times: UrlRedirect: /404_301.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/blaaaah/404.aspx : BEGIN Processing URL

IIS Redirect:
UrlRedirect: /404_301.aspx?404;http://mysite.ca:80/blaaaah/ : BEGIN Processing URL

I only want to allow the .NET redirect.

Comment: thats asp.net putting in `aspxerrorpath`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET aspxerrorpath in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267138/asp-net-aspxerrorpath-in-url)

Comment: If aspxerrorpath is only used if the error is caught by .NET, how do we enforce that IIS does not check for it too?

Comment: You can try the url rewriting http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing