# Writing a URL in webforms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have inherited a project written in .net webforms, basically just an old site that needed to be skinned/made responsive. All of that is done and functions as it should. However I noticed that the old version of the site didn't contain a 404 page, something that I feel is necessary for this site. I've made a 404 page but what I want to do is display the URL on the page. So it'd be something like

```
<div>
    <h1>Something went wrong with</h1>
    <h2>Page URL here</h2>
</div>
```

I know in MVC.net you can write `http://www.domainname.com@(Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"]`
but whats the equivalent in webforms?

FYI the "backend" of each page is written in VB

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you asking how to call a page with a querystring or how to get the querystring out of the called page?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make my question clearer. What I want to do is display the url of the page (whatever page the error occurs on) where my example says <h2>...</h2>. The example with QueryString is in MVC but this project is webforms, hence me needed a little help on this

Comment: You can use the `<%= Request("aspxerrorpath") %>` in WebForms. Assuming you setup the `<customErrors />` in your web.config. Updated for VB, which uses parenthesis and not brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally misread your question and advised Server Variables for "URL", then realised you're on a custom error page, so it would just show the URL you're on.

Perhaps you can use the Referring page?

```
<%=Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]%>
```

Additional info
[ASP.NET aspxerrorpath in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267138/asp-net-aspxerrorpath-in-url)

Comment: Thats okay, sorry if my response sounded rather blunt. Illness + work makes for a bad day. This worked brilliantly, thank-you